# WSO2 CEP Management Console

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep

I have installed WSO2 CEP on Linux. But when I tried to open the management console with the https:///carbon/, it says "The website is not available."

I have the WSO2 CEP running (and it said WSO2 Carbon started in 19 sec).
Is this because I didn't install the CEP properly?

Please help. I am new to the WSO2..

Comment: if CEP server running on local machine ,You can access management console via `https://localhost:9443/carbon` URL

Comment: So I cannot access via a remote machine?

Comment: If you need to access it via remote machine, then replace the `localhost` part with CEP server IP address(or host name).

Comment: I had to remotely access to that machine and access from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you started the WSO2 CEP or any other WSO2 products properly, then you can see the management console in

```
https://localhost:9443/
```

With the default configuration all the WSO2 products works in 9443 port. For more information regarding the WSO2 CEP please refer the [1].

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/CEP210/Complex+Event+Processor+Documentation

Regards,

Mohan

Answer (score 0):

Start the server using the command

```
sh wso2server.sh
```

Then when the server start proccess completed, on your browser

```
https://localhost:9443/carbon
```

may be you may got https certification error proceed no mater.

Enjoy